# Mono MVC 2 home route doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, mono, nginx

I'm trying to convert an ASP .NET MVC 2 app to run on nginx/mono 2.8. So far it seems to work quite well except that the default route doesn't work when the path is empty. I am proxying all requests through to the fastcgi server and I get served up with an ASP .NET 404 not found page.

i.e. This doesn't work

```
http://mysite.com
```

But this does

```
http://mysite.com/home
```

My Global.asax.cs file looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // Default route
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                      // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",   // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new string[] {"MyProject.Controllers"}
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Some more info on my setup. I am running OS X 10.6 if that makes any difference. Also the same problem exists for the default route of any areas in the MVC project.

Comment: Does a route like this help? `routes.MapRoute("Root","/",new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"})`

Comment: Yes adding a specific route like that does work but I would rather not do it as IIS and MVC don't require it. I'm not sure if its a problem with Mono or my Nginx setup.

Comment: Agreed. It's not what you want to have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually ran into the same problem and solved it (at least in my situation) by complete mistake...

In the [nginx walkthrough](http://mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx) on the mono project's site, it says to enter these lines in your nginx.conf file:

```
index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
```

Well, I set this up in the exact same way (or so I thought) on two VMs.  Problem is, one VM had it's root url work and one didn't.  What it turned out to be was that I forgot the semi-colon on the 'index' line on the VM that worked, so that the 'fastcgi_index' line was interpreted as part of the 'index' line.

So on the VM that didn't work, I removed that semi-colon.  And guess what?  It worked.  So then I added the semi-colon and entirely removed the 'fastcgi_index' line and it still worked.  So based on this anecdotal evidence and some guess work, I'd say that the 'fastcgi_index' line should not be included in MVC applications.  Well, at least MVC 3, I haven't tested anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the nginx configuration from this page?: http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx

My guess would be the default document is getting in the way.

Comment: This is totally stupid, but what if you add a beginning slash to the route url: "/{controller}/{action}/{id}". Only thing I can think of considering @Alex's suggestions technically works, and your Area default routes also don't work (meaning your default document shouldn't be a problem)